# How to remove mounted Docker volume directory on host without root permissions

Tags: docker, file-permissions, docker-volume

I have the following problem.

I unintentionally mounted a Docker volume on a host machine on which I don't have root permissions.  Now, I get a 'Permission denied' error while trying to delete the directory, because the Docker container was created with the default root user.

```
x@y:~/app/xy$ ls -ld data
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Apr  7 16:26 data
x@y:~/app/xy$ rm -rf data
rm: cannot remove 'data/data/binlog.000005': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'data/data/undo_002': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'data/data/server-key.pem': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'data/data/ibdata1': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'data/data/client-cert.pem': Permission denied
...
rm: cannot remove 'data/dump/client-key.pem': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'data/dump/ca.pem': Permission denied
x@y:~/app/xy$
```

Information: This Docker container was removed.

I looked for solutions, but found any yet.

Have you any suggestions how I can solve my problem?

Kind regards,
Martin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go into the parent directory. Run a container as root and remove the directory

```
cd ~/app/xy
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app alpine rm -rf data
```

See this if you want to convince someone that they might as well give you root on the host: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface.
Of course that might back-fire and they'll take away your docker privileges :)